# How to properly add index signature to object

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, index-signature

I have following errors (solution is working):

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index
>   signature. [7017]

Code:

```
const createCollection = (jsonObject: object, namesObject: object): INameHex[] => {
  return Object.keys(jsonObject).map(itemKey => {
    return {
      name: namesObject[itemKey],
      hex: jsonObject[itemKey],
    }
  })
}
```

I tried adding interface instead of object (maybe incorrectly), something like - `jsonObject: IProps`. But it is not helping since my object (jsonObject argument) looks like that:

```
  success: string
  error: string
  [propName: string]: string
```

or

```
  default: string
  [propName: string]: string
```

so the object structure differs. 
So I would really like to know how to resolve no index signature error in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it look like what you want?

```
interface JSONObj {
    success: string
    error: string
    [propName: string]: string // this is an index signature 
}

interface NamesObj {
    default: string
    [propName: string]: string // this is an index signature
}

const createCollection = (jsonObject: JSONObj | NamesObj, namesObject: NamesObj): INameHex[] => {
    return Object.keys(jsonObject).map(itemKey => {
      return {
        name: namesObject[itemKey],
        hex: jsonObject[itemKey],
      }
    })
  }
```

It produces no errors and is perfectly correct from the types POV.

Comment: It is not a solution for this code since jsonObject can be of type JSONObj  or NamesObj or 2 more different objects. They all have the same property [propName: string]: string

Comment: @Marta Then you just make it a union. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes - thank you, that is what I needed. Such an easy solution and I spent hours on that already

Comment: @Marta glad I could help!